# Authorization header in Http Request in linkedin

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

Hi in my servlet code I am requesting the server with access_token on behalf of user i am able to request with below code:

```
OAuthRequest request2 = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET,"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,email-address)?oauth2_access_token="+accesstok);
```

But How i can request with Authorization Header like below:

```
GET /v1/people/~ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.linkedin.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Bearer AQXdSP_W41_UPs5ioT_t8HESyODB4FqbkJ8LrV_5mff4gPODzOYR
```

I am using in the below way but not wrking:

```
private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-   name,email-address) HTTP/1.1 Host: api.linkedin.com Connection: Keep-Alive Authorization: Bearer ";
Object AccessToken=  o.get("access_token"); 

String accesstok=AccessToken.toString();

OAuthRequest request2 = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET,PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL+accesstok);
```

Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the `apache.http` library for that. You don't need some OAuth-library or anything. The OAuth protocol is so 'easy' to handle, that you can do it with normal http requests. Here an example with the *apache-http* library.

**[EDIT]** I changed the code to give you a full example, how to use those libraries.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class OAuthConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();  // the http-client, that will send the request
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("");   // the http GET request
            httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer AQXdSP_W41_UPs5ioT_t8HESyODB4FqbkJ8LrV_5mff4gPODzOYR"); // add the authorization header to the request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet); // the client executes the request and gets a response
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();  // check the response code
            switch (responseCode) {
                case 200: { 
                    // everything is fine, handle the response
                    String stringResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());  // now you have the response as String, which you can convert to a JSONObject or do other stuff
                    break;
                }
                case 500: {
                    // server problems ?
                    break;
                }
                case 403: {
                    // you have no authorization to access that resource
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | ParseException ex) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

And here you can find the `jar` files which you can add as a library:

[Apache HTTP-Core v 4.3.3](http://wwwftp.ciril.fr/pub/apache//httpcomponents/httpcore/binary/httpcomponents-core-4.3.3-bin.zip) 
[Apache HTTP-Client v 4.3.6](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/apache//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.3.6-bin.zip)

You can also download that jars from the [Apache page](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

As you will see, the libraries provide you with everything to handle all Requests you may need to access the API (`GET POST DELETE..`). You can change the headers and handle what ever content you get as a response. I know it looks complicated, but with this you will have full control over you OAuth requests and don't need to rely on any library.

**[Yet another EDIT]**
When you download the zip files from the Apache page you need to unpack them and the `jar` file you need is within the `lib` folder.

```
httpcomponents-core-4.3.3
   +-examples
   +-lib
      +-commons-cli-1.2.jar
      +-httpcore-4.3.3.jar   <-- this one you need
      +-httpcore-ab-4.3.3.jar
     ...
```

and the same with the `httpClient`

```
httpcomponents-client-4.3.6
   +-examples
   +-lib
      +- commons-codec-1.6.jar
      +- ...
      +- httpclient-4.3.6.jar  <-- this one
      +- ...
```

Comment: hi GameDroids, Iam getting the error at import package: The import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder cannot be resolved I added the  following jars: commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar

Comment: i am getting compilation error at: HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

Comment: @Raj: Sorry, it took me so long. I edited my answer and added a full example. Also I looked up the right libraries – they changed a little bit in the newer versions and I guess this is where your error came from. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank You GameDroids it worked statically, but when i used in servlet it threw an error at HttpClientBuilder. i was able to manage in the below way :    OAuthRequest request2 = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET,"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,email-address)");//?oauth2_access_token="+accesstok);
                request2.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accesstok);
                Response response2 = request2.send();