# Getting a 401 Error when trying to get Basic User Profile in LinkedIn

Tags: reactjs, react-native, linkedin-api

I am using a [plugin](https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-linkedin) to integrate linkedin signin in my app. However, I am currently facing an issue when trying to get the basic profile from the linkedin after getting the access token.

```
  <LinkedInModal
                            ref={ (linkedInModal) => {
                                this.linkedinButton = linkedInModal;
                            }}
                            permissions={['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'rw_company_admin', 'w_share']}
                            clientID="secret"
                            clientSecret="secret"
                            redirectUri="secret"
                            renderButton={this.renderLinkedInButton.bind(this)}
                            onSuccess={
                                token => {
                                    console.log(token);
                                    axios
                                    .get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json')
                                    .then(user => console.log(user))
                                    .catch(error => console.log(error));
                                }
                            }
                            onSignIn={user => console.log(user)}
                        />
```

Although I am able to successfully get the token. But the `axios.get()` returns an error:- `Request failed with status code 401`. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 401 means you are unauthorized. I think you may need to provide some authorization header along with the request

Answer (score 1):

Try providing the Authorization header with the token you get:

```
onSuccess = {
  token => {
    console.log(token);
    let config = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`  //ES6 template string, u may also use '+'
      }
    };
    axios
    .get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json', config)
    .then(user => console.log(user))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

This is how it is for Google login API, don't know if it will work. Please let me know if it did :)

Comment: unfortunately nope

Comment: Ok I did some research, and I think you have to prefix 'Bearer' with the token ( See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200634/authorization-header-in-http-request-in-linkedin and https://github.com/alexandrzavalii/Linkify/blob/master/src/api/linkedin.js ) . I've updated my answer. See if this works. If not look at the links I have given, especially the 2nd one to github.

Answer (score 0):

`onSuccess` returns the token as an object with `access_token` key. So if you add the token to request headers -like below- it will work.

```
<LinkedInModal
    onSuccess={
        token => {
            console.log(token.access_token);
            axios
            .get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json',
                {
                  headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + token.access_token,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "x-li-format": "json"
                  }
                }
            )
            .then(user => console.log(user))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    }
/>
```